# Was the "cardiac ward building" of Al-Shifa hospital "completely destroyed" (by an airstrike) Sunday, Nov 12, 2023?

Tags: israel-hamas-war

Something like this should be verifiable even with the current level of the fog of war, if not with respect to the exact date, at least whether the building is still around (from satellite photos etc.)

[France24](https://www.france24.com/en/live-news/20231115-gaza-hospitals-caught-in-the-middle-of-israel-hamas-war):

> The Hamas government's deputy health minister told AFP on Sunday [Nov 12] that an Israeli airstrike had "completely destroyed" the cardiac ward building [of Al-Shifa].

[Al-Jazeera also reports](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/11/12/israeli-strikes-in-gaza-kill-at-least-13-destroy-al-shifas-cancer-ward) that event, but there are no images/footage.

> Witnesses inside al-Shifa Hospital told the AFP news agency that “violent fighting” had raged around the hospital all Saturday night.
>
> One air strike destroyed the hospital’s cardiac ward, Gaza officials said, while electricity cuts shut off incubators in the neonatal unit hosting around 40 babies and ventilators for others receiving urgent care.

Was there at least a building in the Al-Shifa hospital compound "completely destroyed" on Sunday (or thereabout), and can its original purpose at least be ascertained?

Comment: Can we say that zero provided photo evidence on such a notable claim is evidence to the contrary?

Comment: One quote says "cardiac ward building" and the other says "cardiac ward." Is it in a separate building or is it one part of a larger building?

Comment: @DavidConrad: how should I know?

Comment: It might be difficult to find out if the building is gone if you don't even know if it was a building to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

[According to CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/interactive/2024/01/middleeast/gaza-hospitals-destruction-investigation-intl-cmd/), which has some footage from inside--taken from an upper floor, it was part of the wall of maternity building that was blown on Nov 10, apparently by a 120mm tank round.

CNN reports an attack on Nov 11 too, hitting the pediatric unit and the ICU, but the footage posted by CNN on that is much less clear, just an inside filled with dust. OTOH textually they say:

> One of the clips captured the aftermath of strikes on the ICU, which was covered in dust and rubble. Holes were visible in the walls that were consistent with the shape left behind by Israeli tank missiles, Garlasco told CNN.

The holes are not visible in the footage posted by CNN though.

I'm still unsure where the "cardiac" unit was in the hospital, but that seems to be the sum of the attacks during those days, at least according to CNN.